# How to work with .NET CLR?

Tags: .net, clr, debugging

I want to implement a small `debugger` for my company, anybody has any idea how to do this? Actually how to start working with .NET **CLR**

**Update :** I actually want to cehck a simple script with .NET clr, for instance

```
set a 12
set simulator
move a2 17
```

This is a simple script and I want to check the form of statements with CLR, is it possible or I have to implement a simple in-line validator for it?

Comment: Is there a good reason that existing .NET debuggers won't work?

Comment: @pickypg, actually it will use to check another script with .NET e.g: checking android command with .NET

Comment: Can you edit your question and show an example of what you hope to accomplish? From the sounds of it, you simply want to get the response from an existing tool/script, and not "implement a small debugger."

Comment: Do you want a debugger that runs on .net CLR which debugs a (or any) foreign language script? Trying to understand the need here..

Comment: Maybe you can start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very interesting sample of a managed debugger available from Microsoft here: [CLR Managed Debugger (mdbg) Sample 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ce94e626-c43d-419c-8538-173f6a042ef5) (this one targets the CLR 4 but there is also a version for CLR 2 available).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if writing your own debugger is the right answer to your problem.

- I'm assuming that there would be on-the-shelf/already-invented Android debuggers available today that will help you get your job done faster.. than writing your own debugger.
- However if this is for the purpose of learning how to extend Visual Studio / the debugger, then the link that malkia posted in the comments should be your starting point.